# jQuery foreach array object

Tags: jquery, arrays, radio-button

I have made an array of element ID's for radio buttons like so:

```
var buttons = [$('#first'), $('#second'), $('#third'), $('#fourth')];
```

What I am now trying to do is, check to see if each one is checked and if so, add a class to something, else add a class to something else. I know how do this separately for each individual **id**:

```
if($('#first').is(':checked')) { 
    $('.cb-enable').addClass('selected');
}
else {
    $('.cb-disable').addClass('selected');
}
```

I tried using `if($('buttons').is(':checked')) {` but it doesn't work.

Can someone please helps me on this one?

Comment: That's an array of jquery objects, not an array of element id's. also, what does `$('buttons')` have to do with your buttons array? None of your code ever uses the buttons array.

Comment: `buttons.each(function(index, value){value.is(':checked')});`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are `.cb-*` elements?

Comment: Are there no satisfactory answers to your question here? You have not accepted or voted them. If anything is unclear, I will be glad to further assist you.

Comment: my bad, I completely forgot about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo: http://jsbin.com/UpUk/1/edit

```
  <button class="check">Tell me what is checked</button>
  <input type="radio" class="checkable">
  <input type="radio" class="checkable">
  <input type="radio" class="checkable">
  <input type="radio" class="checkable">
  <input type="radio" class="checkable">

var $radios = $('.checkable');

$('.check').click(function() {
  $radios.each(function(index, item) {
    if ($(item).is(':checked')) {
      alert('item: '+index+' is checked!');
    }
  });
});
```

It is generally better to use classes, and you don't need to deal with each item individually to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Here's a better version that deals with switching classes. It may be more than what you're looking for, but I don't know quite what you're using this for.

http://jsbin.com/UpUk/3/edit

That should be plenty to help you understand how to approach your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var buttons = $('#first:checked,#second:checked,#third:checked,#fourth:checked');
if (buttons.length>0)
{
...
} else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

`$(elem).prop("checked")`

to get `true` or `false` value if the radio button is checked or is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
        $('input[type=radio]').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
               $('.cb-disable').addClass('selected');
            else 
               $('.cb-enable').addClass('selected');
        }
```

You may not need the index but it will be incremental in order it is found in the dom like what you attempted depending on the details of what your trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons = [$('#first'), $('#second'), $('#third'), $('#fourth')];

$.each(buttons, function(i,el){
  alert( el[0].checked );
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OROc/1/)